# Trigger android permission within given time

Tags: react-native, timer, android-permissions

I am trying to make sure that android permission displays within a given time of 2.5 seconds. But instead, it does automatically after rendering. I tried with TimeOut and setInterval, but maybe the syntax structure is whats out of place. Can anyone suggest a solution, please

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
 navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization()
    }
    //state for opened toggle and combine with android platform
    else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

      async function requestlocationPermission() {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
              title: 'Location permission',
              message:
                'Just for location ',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
              buttonPositive: 'OK',
            },
          );
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log('location enabled');
          } else {
            console.log('location denied');
          }
        } catch {
          console.warn(err)
        }
      }
      setInterval(requestlocationPermission(), 2500)

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval function takes a function as first parameter, the way you tried to call `setInterval(requestlocationPermission(), 2500)` is the issue here.

Because javascript will try to get the result of any given function execution to interpret as a parameter, your function here is executed instantly *before* the 2500 ms timeout. Javascript basically thinks that the function will return another function that will in turn be executed after the timeout.

Here are your two options:

Passing the function as a variable:  (recommended option)
`setInterval(requestlocationPermission, 2500)`

Passing a wrapping function:
`setInterval(() => {requestlocationPermission()}, 2500)`